# Problem using create view and explain plan

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to test the efficiency of this query using **explain plan for**.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
(CREATE VIEW TOPTEAM AS  
    SELECT T1.Team TEAMS, COUNT(*) TIMES 
    FROM TeamsDivision T1
    WHERE (P1.Division = 1 AND
          (2 = (SELECT T2.Division
                FROM TeamsDivision T2
                WHERE (T2.Team = T1.Team AND T2.Season = (T1.Season + 1) )))
    )
    GROUP BY T1.Team     
    ORDER BY TIMES DESC;

SELECT TEAMS, TIMES 
FROM  TOPTEAM
WHERE ROWNUM < 6;

DROP VIEW TOPTEAM);

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

The query works without the explain plan but when I use it I get this errors:

```
CREATE VIEW TOPTEAM AS
 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword


FROM  TOPTEAM
      *
ERROR at line2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I used explain plan on queries without create view and they worked. I don't know what is causing the error I have tried changing the parenthesis but I get the same errors. The only time it works is when I put explain plan before *SELECT TEAMS, TIMES*. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `EXPLAIN PLAN` says

> The EXPLAIN PLAN statement displays execution plans that the optimizer
> chooses for SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements.

Source: [SQL Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.html#GUID-BE9E3808-81AF-4868-B8B2-656E3940B892)

You can probably fish out the execution plan of the `CREATE VIEW` statement, but it will be uninteresting. Only the syntax of the query is checked, your access to the tables, and the query will be stored in `USER_VIEWS`.

I guess what you want to know is the performance of the query itself. You'd do this with

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT TEAMS, TIMES 
  FROM TOPTEAM
 WHERE ROWNUM < 6;
```

Comment: I'm happy to hear that, but it's not necessary or convention on stackoverflow. However, you have the option to accept one answer so that other people know it solved your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The SQL Tuning Guide isn't completely accurate here - `EXPLAIN PLAN` can work with *some* DDL statements. For example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924156/409172) I use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to generate an estimate for how long it will take to build an index. (But it doesn't work for `CREATE VIEW`, and I agree that probably wouldn't help even if it did work.)